# Order lists lexicographically using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of lists (int type). Example:

```
1 5 7 2 3
1 7
1 4 1 2 3 4
```

And i want to order them lexicographically.

Example output:

```
1 4 1 2 3 4
1 5 7 2 3
1 7
```

And I'm asking because I can't figure out how. Google has nothing interesting to say.

Comment: Are they ordered ignoring length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `IComparer<List<int>>` and use it with LINQ's `OrderBy` method:

```
public class ListComparer : IComparer<List<int>> {
    public int Compare(List<int> x, List<int> y) // > 1, == 0, < -1
        => x.Zip(y, (x1, y1) => (x1,y1))
            .Where(xy => xy.x1 != xy.y1)
            .Select(xy => xy.x1 > xy.y1 ? 1 : -1)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(x.Count > y.Count ? 1 : x.Count == y.Count ? 0 : -1)
            .First();
}
```

NOTE: If a list is a prefix of another the list, the shorter list is sorted first. If two lists are equal, they remain in their original order.

With this, you can

```
var ans = src.OrderBy(x => x, new ListComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `.OrderBy` to sort the list of lists. You want to sort lexicographically so you need to sort on the strings you have described in your question:

```cs
static string GetKey(IEnumerable<int> list) => string.Join(' ', list);
```

Provide the array `new[] { 1, 5, 7, 2, 3 }` it will return the string `"1 5 7 2 3"`.

Here's your data (these are arrays, not lists but it doesn't matter):

```cs
var listOfLists = new[]
{
    new[] { 1, 5, 7, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 1, 7 },
    new[] { 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
};
```

And here is how to sort the data:

```cs
var sorted = listOfLists.OrderBy(list => GetKey(list));
```

At this point `sorted` is an `IEnumerable` and you have to enumerate it by using `foreach` or calling `.ToList` or similar to actually create a new list.

Notice that this only works because all the numbers are one digit numbers. If you need to support longer numbers you will have to modify `GetKey` to support your new requirement. Also, with one digit numbers you actually don't need spaces between the digits.

Comment: I seriously doubt when OP said "lexicographically" they mean 10,2,21,3...

Comment: Any more clues how to properly create GetKey? Surely ordering it can't be that hard.

Comment: @Perro12: I'm confused about your question. What clues are you looking for and what is hard? Did I not understand your problem specification correctly?